# Method to change passwords with Mac OS X Server

Tags: mac-osx, password, mac-osx-server, openldap

I'm hoping to figure out the best possible way to force password changes for our users. We are running Mac OS X Server 10.6.2 and most of the desktop are Mac OS X 10.5.8. I can easily go into the Open Directory and force users to change password at login.

The problem, is that most users do NOT connect to the shares and would never be asked to change their password. If, they go to Go, Connect to Server, type server address, then it would ask them here.

We tried binding the desktops to the open directory server in the hope that when the user logged back in they would be prompted but even that doesn't seem to work properly. Another idea was to create a separate page, that can be accessed for inside where they can change their passwords.

We have a number of services tied into the OD already so we really need a good way to manage these password changes.

Any solutions would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit based on comment thread:

You could push a script to everyone with Apple Remote Desktop that attempts to mount a sharepoint. Or, as you said above, Apple does provide a password changing website, but again, that would require emailing everyone and telling them to go to the website, which many might ignore.

How to set up an OD user who doesn't have a network home folder:

1. Create the user in Workgroup Manager.
2. Click on "Home" in the segmented control bar at the top.
3. Click the plus button, leave the first two fields blank, and type /Users/username, where you would replace username with the short name of the user. At this point, you'd want to make sure that the user you're setting up doesn't already have a local account with the same name.
4. Click Okay, then make sure that the entry you created is selected. It should have a harddrive icon and be listed as /Users. Click "create home now", then click save.

That's it! If you don't specify that the user should get a local folder and leave it as no home folder, you'll actually be unable to log in at all. Now you have all of the management you'd get with having a bound Machine *and* a network account, without the extra storage overhead (and possible long login times).

Old answer: I don't want to seem condescending but you really need to learn more before you jump into this. The Lynda training series videos for snow leopard server are great, or grab a book from the bookstore. Snow Leopard Server is very picky. Everything needs to be set up properly and in a very specific order. The best advice I can give you is to start fresh - open up a book or start the video and start from the beginning. Set up DNS exactly how they say, then wipe and reinstall OS X server (remember to run software update!) and go from there with a fresh start. I myself had to do that several times on a test server before I got the process down right.

Comment: @jack-lawrence I just wanted to revisit this issue once again. I know its been awhile. In particular I have gone through the Snow Leopard Server manual and Open Directory Admin. I appreciate the advice to start fresh but given the impact that would have on our network it most definitely is NOT an option. I'd love to be able to do this if it would mean being able to force a password policy to all users on the network but seems like a rather daunting task. Anyway, if you or anyone else has any further ideas I'd love to hear!

Comment: Hmmm okay thanks for narrowing down the problem. I didn't realize everyone had local accounts. How do you manage them? Apple Remote Desktop? If so, you could push a script to everyone to attempt to mount a sharepoint. As you said above, Apple *does* provide a password changing website, but again, that would require emailing everyone and telling them to go to the website, which many might ignore.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if you'd see this since its been awhile. We do use Apple Remote Desktop for managing the systems. That's an interesting idea, so pushing an attempt to mount a sharepoint would in a sense force them to hit the server which would then get them to change their password. I wish we could easily do the bind just because it's so much cleaner in the long run. But the fact that we have local user accounts makes it harder. We don't care about copying data to server. But one issue we ran into was if the local user didn't match the network account we had troubles binding.

Comment: Yep, the problem you outline is one of the many issues that mass-migrating from local accounts to server accounts has. It's really a huge nightmare because of all the little things that need to match up and work perfectly, and it's hard to test everything before deployment. You could try slowly migrating into it. Whenever you give someone a new machine or re-image it, bind them to the server, give them an OD Mobile Home account (offline data access/sync), and move their user data. It's totally worth it. Let me know if the script solves the problem or if you have any other questions. - Jack

Comment: Ok cool, I really appreciate all your help. So far we've been binding the machines when we get them. Is it required to setup the Mobile Home account? The reason I ask is because we don't have any intention of storing all the users data on the servers since this would take up a lot of space.

Comment: Nope, no need to use a Mobile Home account. I'll detail above what you need to do if you don't want home folder on the server.

Comment: That's very helpful. At this point most everyone is setup in the Work Group Manager so all we need to do is setup the Mobile Home account. You know of the best way to work around the local account issue (same name)? We seem to have a good number of people that have the same account on their system. I know we tried to just change the name in the past and it seemed like we may have been missing something. Not sure if this something worth automating or not. When I last pulled a report using RD seemed like about half (~150 people) had identical names on the local system.

Comment: Hmmm. Well here's the problem, at its root: local accounts and server accounts get different IDs so technically, the client can differentiate between identical shortnames. The problem lies, simply, in the fact that you can't have two accounts in the /Users folder with the same folder name. I think you might just have to delete the local user and user folder after you've transferred data. You should try setting up a test case (get a mac, make a local user and write some data to the desktop, make an identical user on the server, bind the mac, log in with the server account) and see what happens

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll try setting up a test box and see how it works. Thanks again for all your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OD for login? If the password is expired, they should be prompted at login.

Comment: We aren't using OD for login. Is there a simple way to turn that on?

Comment: @Aaron - Add the OD Master to the seach paths for the client machines. The only thing is that this will create new home folders, as OS X would think it's a new account (and technically it is). You can certainly write a script that would add the search path and then on login, copy the contents of the old home folder to the new one though.

Comment: Okay, I do have the OD added in the Directory Utility. And under Search Policy I have /LDAPv3/opendir.server.com. Above this /BSD/local and /Local/Default are greyed out. Is this correct? Does this mean the OD is in the search path?

Comment: If you have local accounts on the local machine that are the same as the names in OD, they will use the local account first since /Local/Default is above /LDAPv3/opendir.server.com. You can either remove the local account and login normally, this should use OD authentication. Or you can drag the OD server above /Default/Local in the search path. Either way.

Comment: I see what you mean. For some reason, it is not allowing for me to drag the OD server above the /Default/Local search path.

Comment: @Aaron - That may be the expected behavior, I'm not in the office to check (highways were flooded out today - working from home :)) On a test machine, you might just delete a local account with a corresponding OD account and try logging in.

Comment: Ok I had to leave but will try in morning.

Comment: I did try to check this out on a seperate machine. I found that on OS X 10.6.3 there is the option under Accounts, Login Options to Join a Network Account Server. I setup the open directory server, made sure it was listed in the search policyy, logged out then tried logging in on my server account. For some reason, it is unable to login, the window just shakes and acts like it is the wrong credentials even though they are correct. It even for a second shows the Full user name as in OD. When I give good user and bad pass it just shakes prompt. Any ideas? Again most users are on 10.5.8 anyway.

Comment: @Aaron - Unfortunately no. We use the Magic Triangle with OD and AD. We use the AD part for actual authentication.

Comment: Okay, I have reason to believe there is something missing on the OD itself. When I try logging into the system, it does show up on the logs and tells me KERBEROS-LOGIN-CHECK for the user is in good standing, then authentication successful. Then it says GETPOLICY: user. Not sure if this helps at all.

Comment: @Aaron - Like I said, I can't be much more help with OD logins, as I have no experience with them. Everything I've done is SSO with Active Directory.